# Using DB2 in a mixed .net core / .net 4.7 project

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, db2

We want to reuse our .net 4.7 library (C#) to Access an DB2 10.5 database from a new .net core 2.2 Project. Unfortunaltely I get errors if I open the Connection:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "SQL1159  Initialization error with
>   DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 2, tokens
>   D:\Projekte\Main-Branch-IpIdentity\Services\InvoiceApi\InvoiceApi\bin\db2app64.dll,
>   , Process Owner

The missing ddl can be found in path under C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN.
I copied all out of this directory to the project output directory and got:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "SQL1159  Initialization error with
>   DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 10, tokens 0.0.0, 10.5.5, Process
>   Owner:

I wrote a console project in .net core, calling a .net core dll with Access to DB2:

```
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var count = DB2AccessCore.Db2Access.GetCount();
      }
   }

namespace DB2AccessCore

  public class Db2Access
  {
     public static int GetCount()
     {
        var con = new DB2Connection("....");
        con.Open();

        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data.abstimmfeldausschnitt";
        var a = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
        return (int)a;
     }
  }
```

}
}

The example works fine, also if I use the same Code in a .net 4.7 console and dll. But I call the 4.7 dll from the core console I get a exception:

> System.AccessViolationException: "Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Sounds not good…

What do I wrong, or is it not possible with DB2 to mix between core and 4.7? Has anybody already done this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use the IBM DB2 Nuget package.

Comment: I use the package IBM.Data.Db2 v10.0.5.5 (with local installed 10.5.5 Client) in the 4.7 dll